# Fluent Validations to know that string value is between 1 to 100

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

I have a string object of amount.
I want to check with fluent validation that amount is between 1 to 100.

```
RuleFor(x=>x.TotalAmount)
               .NotEmpty()
               .WithLocalizedMessage(() => AccountResources.Validation_MissingAmountValue)
               .InclusiveBetween(1, 999999999)
               .WithLocalizedMessage(() => AccountResources.Validation_InvalidAmountValue);
```

Here inclusiveBetween is not working as amount is of string type.

Answer (score 0):

Use Transform() method and parse the value to type you want.
Here is the link you can Check.

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/transform.html